# The issue - Rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus, english

Solve the following rebus puzzle:

```
 ISSUES 
 ISSUES  ISSUES   
 ISSUES  ISSUES  ISSUES  
 ISSUES  ISSUES  ISSUES  ISSUES
```

Comment: Man, you got a lot of issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not the best pun, if the solution indeed is

> "Ten issues" = "Tennis shues" = **"Tennis shoes"**

Comment: could be teen issues? :D

Answer (score 2):

My answer:

> Steps on my tennis shoes.  Credit to Gamow +1